# error using pointer to char instead of char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does simple C code receive segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-does-simple-c-code-receive-segmentation-fault)

I am working in Ubuntu using the GCC compiler with C language; I have this program:

```
void foo(char *word)
{
    //something stupid
    *word = 'z';
}

int main()
{

    char word1[] = "shoe";
    char *word2 = "shoe";

    foo(word1);
    printf("%s", word1);
    foo(word2);
    printf("%s", word2);
}
```

So what's the difference? With the latter I get a `segmentation fault` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char word1[] = "shoe";` creates an array of 5 characters and copies the string literal "shoe" into it (which can be modified).

`char *word2 = "shoe";` creates a pointer to the string literal "shoe" (which cannot be modified).

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that the first one is valid code, whereas the behaviour of the second one is undefined (since you are not allowed to modify a string literal). See the [FAQ](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html).

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time someone asked about modifying a `const char*`...

Comment: @EdS.: But it *isn't* a `const char*`.  String literals in C are not `const`; it's just undefined behavior to attempt to modify them.  (They are `const` in C++.)

Comment: Right, it is a poor design decision.  They *should* be const, but I admit I missed the C tag and assumed C++.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `char *word2 = "shoe";` is being stored in the `.rodata` [data section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment):

```
$ readelf -p .rodata adum

String dump of section '.rodata':
  [     4]  shoe
  [     9]  %s
```

(This would be easier to see if you stored `shoe` in one variable and `foot` in the other variable.)

The compiler is allowed to store the string constant in read-only memory because the standard doesn't allow modifying string literals.

Your first case is an explicitly-initialized character array; the standard *does* allow modifying those, so they are not stored in a read-only section.